# How Lists (specifically, RecyclerView with CardViews) in Android work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

Forgive me for asking this question, but I am new to Android development and although I am trying to go through the basics on the developer.android.com website, most of the samples (even though they say they're built for Android Studio) are not already setup to use Gradle and thus do not build unless you migrate them over to Gradle, and when you do that it either doesn't do anything or you get tons of errors.

I've been trying to learn how to create Lists.

I've read a bunch of tutorials on this from different sources. I've read the Android documentation. I've even read through the source code of the Android samples even though I couldn't get a few of them to build.

I've tried writing my own code but I just don't understand the logic (for lack of a better word) behind creating List controls/elements/views in Android and binding/inserting data to them.

I am trying to create a [CardView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) list. I don't understand how to create a List (of any type) and insert *items* into it at runtime (in a foreach loop for example). I thought that CardView was a list of its own, but it turns out it's just another control/view, kind of like a list item, and you add many to a list. I've read that you should put CardViews in a RecyclerView (which I think is a list). But all of the samples I've tried don't even build due to errors. So this just adds to the confusion while trying to learn how things work.

How do I create a RecyclerView list and add CardView items to it at runtime in a for/foreach loop, for example?

[image]

Comment: I would really suggest on trying to build a simple ListView and dynamically add items to that to get a better understanding of how to implement it.  If you need an example I can post it below.  Or if you want any other information I can possibly help you.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneH I would really appreciate it if you could post an example.

Comment: Yes.  I am putting it together now

Comment: I put together an example with a CardView. Have you implemented the cardView In your dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

I have put together an example. I will update it with explanation when I get home.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:id="@+id/etTitle" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:id="@+id/etDescription" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/lvList" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_row_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**ListData.java**

```
public class ListData {
    String title;
    String Description;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

**ListAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
    Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ListViewHolder view = (ListViewHolder) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new ListViewHolder(context);
        }
        ListData log = getItem(position);
        view.setLog(log);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**ListViewHolder**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ListViewHolder extends LinearLayout {
    Context mContext;
    ListData mLog;

    public ListViewHolder(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setup();
    }

    public ListViewHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, this);
    }

    public void setLog(ListData log) {
        mLog = log;
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(mLog.getTitle() + "");
        TextView tvDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        tvDescription.setText(mLog.getDescription() + "");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btnAddItem;
    ListView lvList;
    ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    EditText etTitle, etDescription;
    String title = "", description = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList);
        lvList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
        btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                title = etTitle.getText().toString();
                description = etDescription.getText().toString();
                if (title.length() == 0) {
                    title = "Not Title";
                }
                if (description.length() == 0) {
                    description = "No Description";
                }
                ListData mLog = new ListData();
                mLog.setTitle(title);
                mLog.setDescription(description);
                myList.add(mLog);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ListData mLog = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Title: " + mLog.getTitle() + "  Description: " + mLog.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your application id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
}
```

**What it should look like**
[image]

Comment: why is there a linearlayout around your cardview?

Comment: @EugeneH Wow thank you so much. I'm about to start reading through it. I have put CardView in the build dependencies.

Comment: @njzk2 I put this together pretty fast. I actually didn't notice.  I will update my answer, Thanks.

Comment: @RǢF Cool. Let me know if you have any issues and I will get back to you.

Comment: Wow, I just read through it. It's amazing how much extra code you need to write to get a basic list working compared to desktop or Windows phone apps. This will definitely take some getting used to I think! I'm gonna go try this code now :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @RǢF I haven't worked with windows phone or desktop yet but I am curious to see the comparison.  And if you want me to add more to the example, like any other example's like int, double, etc I will update the answer.    Let me know if it works out.

Comment: A quick and dirty desktop sample: ListBox box = new ListBox(); box.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++) { box.Items.Add("Item " + i.ToString()); } Sorry about lack of formatting here I'm on my phone.

Comment: @RǢF ah.  There are simple listViews you can use but in order to create a listView item with more than two text items and custom layouts, you need to typically do what I have provided.  I figure I give you an example of what you will probably use with more advanced views.

Comment: Yeah what you have provided is awesome. Exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @RǢF Awesome.  I started with android about a year ago and the listViews are one of the more complicated parts. It took me some time to get it down. And I still get confused at times haha