# How to post JSON String in android?

Tags: android, json, api, gson, retrofit

I use this answer, how to add multi list data. [How Lists (specifically, RecyclerView with CardViews) in Android work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908680/how-lists-specifically-recyclerview-with-cardviews-in-android-work). I need to post JSON String to api. But I can't get JSON String (Users Name) from User Object. How to get User Name from DeliveryStaff Object > User Object > User Name. It say User Name is required. Because I post **myList** is user object. When I Log it, User Object is shown. But I can't get User Name.

DeliveryStaff.java

```
   [
      {
        "id": 30,
        "user_id": "292",
        ... etc
        "user": {
          "id": 292,
          "name": "Peter",
          ... etc
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 51,
        "user_id": "256",
        ... etc
        "user": {
          "id": 256,
          "name": "Jhon Staff",
          ... etc
        }
      }
    ]
```

ChooseMultiStaff.java

```
ArrayList<DeliveryStaff> myList = new ArrayList<DeliveryStaff>();
lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
multiStaffListAdapter = new multiStaffListAdapter(ChooseMultiStaff.this, myList);
lvList.setAdapter(multiListAdapter);

// add function 
// multiDeliveryStaffList - come from staff spinner onItemSelected (DeliveryStaff multiDeliveryStaffList = (DeliveryStaff) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);)

DeliveryStaff mLog = new DeliveryStaff();
mLog.setUser(multiDeliveryStaffList.getUser());
myList.add(mLog);
multiListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

// post function 

private void PostAddStaff() {
ArrayList<DeliveryStaff> uploadMultiDeliverStaff = new ArrayList<DeliveryStaff>();
for (DeliveryStaff dsl : myList) {
if (dsl.getId() == null) {
uploadMultiDeliverStaff.add(dsl);
}
}

Log.i("List", new Gson().toJson(myList));
NetworkEngine.getInstance().postAddStaff(new Gson().toJson(myList), txt_date_time_display.getText().toString(), new Callback<JsonObject>() {
@Override
public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
// finish - done
}           
});
}

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/addstaffs")
void postAddStaff(
@Field("json") String json,
@Field("pick_up_time") String pick_up_time,
Callback<JsonObject> callback);


 staffname ["51","56"]
    pick_up_time 2016-10-31 12:04
```

Comment: _But I can't get User Name._ Why not? Is there an error?

Comment: It return User Object. I can't get User Name from User Object.

Comment: Show your user class.

Comment: "user": {
          "id": 292,
          "name": "Peter",
          ... etc
        }

Comment: Does `DeliveryStaff` have the `User` in it?

Comment: Yes. In DeliveryStaff "user_id": "292", In User "user": {
          "id": 292,

Comment: Then what is the issue? `myList.get(0).getUser().getName()` will give you the username if you have parsed the `JSON` correctly.

Comment: JSON is correct, Like this, new Gson().toJson(myList.get(0).getUser().getName()) ?? Sir

Comment: `staffname ["51","56"]`. Is this how you should pass it to the API ?

Comment: Server Developer, show it demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JsonObject obj = YOURJSON.getJSONObject(0);
String name = obj.getJSONObject(user).getString(name);
```

Comment: Where, I need to changes. Please, Sir

Comment: you are printing a json , assign it to a jsonObject or JsonArray.
    Log.i("List", new Gson().toJson(myList));

Comment: 'JsonArray array = new Gson().toJson(myList);'

Comment: Error - Required: com.google.gson.JsonObject or JsonArray, Found: java.lang.String I assign like this JsonObject obj  = new Gson().toJson(myList);

Comment: String string = new Gson().toJson(myList); JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string); then, what i need to do? Sir

Comment: are you trying to create a JSON array or trying to get data from Json array ?

Comment: trying to get data (user > user name) from json object & post it to api.

Comment: `JsonObect obj = myList.getJsonObject(0);`

Comment: `String name = obj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");`

Comment: if myList is a JsonArray this will work or else you'll have to convert myList to JsonArray first then use this method.